# Simple ASP.NET File Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a very simple ASP.NET page that uploads an Excel workbook, then processes it. It uses AJAXFILEUPLOAD from the AJAX toolkit on ASP.NET... Here's the markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="ImportWorkbook.aspx.cs" Inherits="Timesheet.ImportWorkbook" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContentPlaceHolder">
<h1 class="topContent">
    Upload CPAS Timesheet Workbooks
</h1>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<br />
<br />
<asp:HiddenField ID="tbTSID" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="tbWorkbookPath" runat="server" />
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="xls,xlsx,xlsm"
    CssClass="dropdown" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Panel ID="ProcessChoices" runat="server" >
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>
        Select how you want this workbook processed:</p>
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbChoices" runat="server" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="2px"
        BorderColor="Black" BackColor="Teal" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="White"
        Width="40%">
        <asp:ListItem Value="True" Selected="True">&nbsp Replace ALL Items in the Timesheet</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="False">&nbsp Add Items from this Workbook to the Existing Timesheet Items</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Text="Validate and Process" 
        BackColor="#B92217" ForeColor="White" BorderColor="#7C1810" 
        BorderStyle="Groove" Font-Names="Tahoma" onclick="btnValidate_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="BottomSpanContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
</asp:Content>
```

The master page and css pages are trivial, formatting only.

Here's the codebehind:

```
 using System;
using System.IO;
using TimesheetUtilites;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AjaxControlToolkit;

    namespace Timesheet
    {

    public partial class ImportWorkbook : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private const string HDriveLocation= "H:\\mtv\\secure\\Construction\\Access\\CPAS WorkArea\\TimesheetUploads\\";
        private string strWorkbookPath;    
        private int currTSID;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
                {
                    tbTSID.Value = Request.QueryString["ID"];            // Storing the Timesheet ID in a hidden Textbox                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbWorkbookPath.Value))
                {
                    ProcessChoices.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            int.TryParse(tbTSID.Value, out currTSID);
            strWorkbookPath = tbWorkbookPath.Value;
        }
        protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            strWorkbookPath = HDriveLocation + Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
            tbWorkbookPath.Value = strWorkbookPath;
            AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(strWorkbookPath);
            ProcessChoices.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool processOption;
            bool.TryParse(rbChoices.SelectedValue, out processOption);
            strWorkbookPath = tbWorkbookPath.Value;
            TimesheetUtilites.ImportTimesheet imp = new ImportTimesheet(currTSID, strWorkbookPath, processOption);       
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is simple. Although the event handler "AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" works fine, and uploads the file in an instant, when I fire the "btnValidate_Click" event, the "tbWorkbookPath.Value" has become an empty string, and the "ProcessChoices.Enabled" propety doesn't change. Needless to say, the "Upload Complete" event handler is the only opportunity I have to capture this file path, so I'm at a loss what I'm doing wrong.

I posted on ASP.NET and go NO answers. Can anyone give me an idea where to start?

Comment: So the problem is that the hidden fields value is resetting to blank string between post backs. Have you tried putting a break point to pinpoint where it's resetting. Try putting a break point in your page_load if it isn't a postback. If that triggers you know it's a whole new request, and you'll have to store your value in a session variable or something

Comment: I've tried a couple things since posting this...
1. I removed the panel. Someone elsewhere suggested I had a scope issue with the panel... no joy.
2. I changed the hidden field session state property to false...no joy...changed back.
3. I changed the hidden field to a (non-hidden) text box. The text box appears ALWAYS to be blank, before AND AFTER the event handler fires.

Comment: Well, storing the path in a Session Variable as one of the answers below suggest should pretty certainly work, but it'd be interesting to see where / why the value is getting wiped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is information you should be storing in your page's ViewState so that it persists between postbacks and resets on page initialization. Change your private string member to something like the following:

```
private string strWorkbookPath {
    get {
        return this.ViewState["strWorkbookPath"];
    }
    set {
        this.ViewState["strWorkbookPath"] = value;
    }
}
```

If you need a primer on what the ViewState is, check out this article on MSDN: [Saving Web Forms Page Values Using View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yfdwycw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It's a bit dated but still communicates the basics of how ViewState operates currently.

Comment: I was excited about this answer (and Anubhav's), but I added your exact code (cut/paste) to my codebehind, and intellisense rejects it: "Non-invocable member'System.Web.UI.Control.ViewState' cannot be used like a method"

Comment: Replace the this.ViewState with Session, that should work, but you should still look into what's causing it to be wiped

Comment: I went to the link you gave me and it helped me fix the error. Need square brackets instead of parentheses...

Comment: I fixed the Viewstate[] issue, and it compiles, but now the value is null instead of ""....

Comment: "Session" fixed it. Works now! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that Jim. I'm a VB.NET developer by day and sometimes I mix up my indexing operators.

Answer (score 0):

Put a hidden field with runat="server" attribute on your page and use the below script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
            var filename = args.get_fileName();
            $("#hiddden_field_id").val(filename);
    }
</script>
```

Now you should be getting the image name in your events.

Comment: This one, I don't understand. Won't that function replace my codebehind event handler? That would be not good....

Comment: Then you can go for other work arounds.. like setting this hidden field's value on your code behind event and accessing it later on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try storing that value in session rather than a hidden field as the page is not reloaded and it was an ajax call. So when the button is clicked for validation, it is actually another request made but the value of the hidden field in this page object and the hidden field is still empty. Once your job is done for that value in session, remove it from there or set it to some different value.